# Get users from table where group=group of another table row but i have id of other table row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**MY USERS TABLE:**

[image]

**GROUP_PERMISSIONS TABLE**

[image]

**problem:**

How can i get all the users(from users table) with the group i.e equal to the group of groups_permissions table but i have the **gid** of the group from groups_permissions table?

**CODE:(that i have tried(it has some other functions also))**

```
$stmt = $db_con->query("SELECT gp.*, s.*, uu.*, ug.* FROM (SELECT * FROM groups_permissions WHERE gid={$_POST['gp_row_id']}) gp, (SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id='1') s, (SELECT username FROM users ORDER BY id) uu, (SELECT username FROM users WHERE `group`=gp.group_name WHERE gp.gid={$_POST['gp_row_id']}) ug");            
$stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    /* FROM GROUP_PERMISSIONS TABLE */
        $response['id'] = $row['gid'];
        $response['group'] = $row['group_name'];
        $response['restricted_pages'] = $row['restricted_pages'];
        $response['restricted_permissions'] = $row['restricted_permissions'];
    /* FROM SETTINGS TABLE */
        $response['site_pages'] = $row['site_pages'];
        $response['site_permissions'] = $row['site_permissions'];
    /* FROM USERS TABLE */
        $active_ids[]= $row['username'];
        $userlist = join(",", $active_ids);
        $string = trim($userlist,'"');
        $response['users'] = $string;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

**FOR EXAMPLE**
if on submitting the form i get the row id `5` (see image above) of a group dsf from groups_permissions ,then i want to get all users with group `dsf` from users table but as i have the id for group from groups_permissions table then ,i dont know what to use but like `Select username from users WHERE group='dsf' from permissions_table but rather select the group by the help of gid`

Comment: Can you elaborate with a sample output

Comment: @Shyamala for example if on submitting the form i get the row id `5` (see image above) of a group `dsf` from groups_permissions ,then i want to get all users with group `dsf` from users table but as i have the id for group from groups_permissions table then ,i dont know what to use but like `Select username from users WHERE group='dsf' from permissions_table but rather select the group by the help of gid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, select should be

```
"SELECT *
FROM users
INNER JOIN permissions_table ON permissions_table.group_name = users.group
WHERE permissions_table.gid = {$_POST['gp_row_id']}"
```

And I would advice to keep group IDs in users table, instead of group names, as it is proper practice for relational databases.

Comment: right but when group is created the autoincreament id auto increase so i am not able to place that in users column because i dont know whats the increament id

Comment: That's where last_insert_id method comes in handy.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php
It is, after group is created, you use this method to get that new ID and use it in next operations.

Comment: where should i place last_insert_id in the following : `    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO groups_permissions(`group_name`, restricted_pages, restricted_permissions) VALUES (:groupname, COALESCE(NULLIF(:rp, ''), restricted_pages), COALESCE(NULLIF(:rps, ''), restricted_permissions))");
    $stmt->bindParam(":groupname", $group_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(":rp", $restricted_pages);
    $stmt->bindParam(":rps", $restricted_permissions);
    if($stmt->execute()){$ok='ok';}else{$not='not';}`

Comment: after statement execute? like `stmt->execute(); $stmt->lastInsertId();` or before execute?

Comment: After execution. Don't be afraid to experiment while you try to figure out things, also google questions and read manuals on stuff, which you are working with. You'll get great experience and knowledge.